# Is there a way to optimize the itterrows code in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

This is the input data

The Closing stock value is calculated by only where there is a value for Opening Stock by adding Opening stock, Purchase Qty and Sold Qty .

[image: Input data]

I want to add values to 'Opening Stock' & 'Closing Stock' with conditions.

1. When the Opening stock value is 0 or blank, it should be filled
   by the Closing Stock of previous record
2. Fill should happen only when the Site and Item code are same for this record and previous record

for i, row in df.iterrows():

```
df['Opening Stock']  = np.where((df['Site'] == df['Site'].shift(1)) & (df['Item Code'] == df['Item Code'].shift(1))& ((df['Opening Stock'] == 0) | (df['Opening Stock'].isna())),df['Closing Stock'].shift(1),df['Opening Stock'])
df['Closing Stock'][i] = df['Opening Stock'][i]+df['Purchase Qty'][i]+df['Sold Qty'][i]
```

This is how the output looks like

[image]

The problem is since the size of the dataset is large it takes hours to complete.

Is there a way to optimise this code?

Comment: @roganjosh Imagine if the opening and closing stock values are available only for the first record. In this case if I don't run the loop, the second value of opening stock will be 1200 but the 3rd value of opening stock will be 0 since the closing stock value of second record is 0.  Therefore, I had to run the loop for each record to calculate opening stock from previous closing stock and closing stock from the formula together.

Comment: Ah, oops, I forgot the first screenshot. Let me re-look

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without any iterative approach. The first step is to convert the `0` values in `Opening Stock` to `np.nan` so that we can fill them in the next step.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'Site': ['site 1', 'site 1', 'site 2', 'site 2'],
                   'Item Code': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
                   'Opening Stock': [1000, 0, 2000, 0],
                   'Closing Stock': [1200, 0, 2250, 0],
                   'Purchase Qty': [500, 100, 400, 300],
                   'Sold Qty': [-300, -200, -150, -100]})

df.loc[df['Opening Stock'] == 0, 'Opening Stock'] = np.nan
df['Opening Stock'] = df.groupby(['Site', 'Item Code'])['Opening Stock'].fillna(df['Closing Stock'].shift(1))
df['Closing Stock'] = df['Opening Stock'] + df['Purchase Qty'] + df['Sold Qty']
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only does the shift. For each shift of opening stock, I want the closing stock value to be calculated based on the new opening stock value, purchase qty and sold qty.

Comment: I want the calculated closing stock value to be the next value of opening stock. This code only does it once.

Comment: @vicky have you actually run it? It gives the exact same output as you show in your question. I don't know what you mean by "only does it once"; as I said earlier, the calculations are vectorized so you don't need to call it in a loop

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'Site': ['site 1', 'site 1', 'site 1', 'site 1'],
                   'Item Code': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
                   'Opening Stock': [1000, 0, 0, 0],
                   'Closing Stock': [1200, 0, 0, 0],
                   'Purchase Qty': [500, 100, 400, 300],
                   'Sold Qty': [-300, -200, -150, -100]})
   For this df, this code wont work.

Comment: @vicky ok, so you need iterative filling. In which case, I don't think there's much you can do without a loop then

Comment: Yes, that's why I wanted to see if there's faster way. Thank you so much for your inputs :)

Answer (score 0):

one way to apply a condition on every row in a Pandas dataframe is [df.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df.apply(
         self.my_function
         args = function_args
         ....
)
```

```
def my_function(self, row, args):
    row['Closing Stock']= row['Opening Stock']+row['Purchase Qty']+row['Sold Qty']
# you can do pretty much whatever you want inside this function
#note: row is a pandas series
   return row  #it return the row modified and inserts it into the dataframe
```

Comment: `apply` runs in a python `for` loop and will not give a significant performance increase